# Convergence of Step Function Defined by Averages

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

For a function $f \in L^2[0,T]$, and a uniform partition $P = \{0=t_0, t_1, \ldots, t_n = T\}$ of the domain, we can define a step function approximation as the average value over each interval in the partition, $$f_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac nT \chi_{[t_{k-1}, t_k]} \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(t)dt.$$
I'm trying to prove that as $n\to \infty$ and the partition becomes arbitrarily fine, $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$. So far, I've got
\begin{align*}
\|f - f_n\|_2^2 & = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} \left( f(t) - \frac nT \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(x) dx \right )^2 dt \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} \left(\frac nT \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(t) dx - \frac nT \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(x) dx \right )^2dt \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} \left(\frac nT \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} f(t) - f(x) dx \right )^2dt\\
& \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \frac nT \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k} \int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_k}(f(t) - f(x))^2dxdt
\end{align*}
Now, I know I can make the inner integral less than any positive $\varepsilon$ with $n\to \infty$ via absolute continuity of the integral. Evaluating the outer integral then gives a $\frac Tn$, so I'm left with $\sum_{k=1}^n \varepsilon$, which goes to infinity in the limit. So I clearly need to capture some other source of "smallness" within my integral.

Since $t$ and $x$ both lie within the interval $[t_{k-1}, t_k]$, I know that they are no more than $\frac nT$ apart. However, my attempts to exploit this with a change of variables have been fruitless. Is there something I'm missing here?

Addendum: I know I can prove convergence of $f_n \to f$ by showing that $\| f_n \|_2$ is uniformly bounded by $\|f\|_2$, and proving convergence for continuous f. However, I'm curious as to whether there's a way to use absolute continuity of the inner integral and the nearness of $t$ and $x$.

Comment: I don't think you can finish this approach without using the density of continuous functions. Basically, you integrate the function $F(x,y)=(f(x)-f(y))^2$ over $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the diagonal $y=x$ and want to show the integral is $o(\epsilon)$. (Note the region of integration has area $\sim \epsilon$). For continuous $f$ this is clear because $F=0$ on the diagonal. By density, this extends to all $f\in L^2$. I don't think there is an easier way to finish.